# Excel VBA Copying data from another workbook using cell reference

Tags: vba, excel, reference

I have the filename stated in cell B1 and I'm trying to import data from another sheet. Currently this is throwing *subscription-out-of-range* error. Any simple way to fix this? Or another preferred way to do this? The only requirement is to have cells containing data (text) from another workbook, not formula referring to it.

```
Sub UpdateFileInfo()
    If (Range("B1") = "") Then
        Range("A2:R200").Value = ""
    Else
        Filename = Range("B1").Value  

        Range("A2:R200") = Workbooks(Filename).GetActiveSheet.Range("A2:R200").Value

    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: What is `GetActiveSheet` ?  Is the workbook you need to read from open?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you already know the source sheet name (e.g.: "Sheet1") you could use this

```
Option Explicit

Sub UpdateFileInfo2()
    With Range("A2:R200") ' reference target range
        If Range("B1") = "" Then ' if currently active sheet B1 cell is empty
            .ClearContents ' clear referenced range content
        Else
            .FormulaR1C1 = "='C:\Users\...\[" & Range("B1").Value & "]Sheet1'!RC" ' fill referenced range with formulas pointing at the corresponding cell in the wanted sheet of the wanted workbook
            .Value = .Value ' get rid of formulas and leave values only
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

otherwise, you could use this pattern:

```
Sub UpdateFileInfo2()
    With Range("A2:R200") ' reference target range
        If Range("B1") = "" Then ' if currently active sheet B1 cell is empty
            .ClearContents ' clear referenced range content
        Else
            .Value = Workbooks.Open(Range("B1").Value).ActiveSheet.Range(.Address).Value ' have refereneced range values as the newly opened workbook activesheet corresponding one
            ActiveWorkbook.Close false ' close newly opened workbook
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

while, should your `Range("B1").Value` not contain the full path of your file, then add it:

```
Sub UpdateFileInfo2()
    With Range("A2:R200") ' reference target range
        If Range("B1") = "" Then if currently active sheet B1 cell is empty
            .ClearContents ' clear referenced range content
        Else
            .Value = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\...\" & Range("B1").Value).ActiveSheet.Range(.Address).Value ' have refereneced range values as the newly opened workbook activesheet corresponding one
            ActiveWorkbook.Close false ' close newly opened workbook
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

---

Comment: Thanks for the easy solution!

Comment: you are welcome. see last edit also. if my answer solved your question then you may consider marking it as accepted. thank you

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this error because the Workbook is not open.

To do that, you'll have to include a line before the command that writes to range("A2:R200") that opens the workbook. But then, you'll have more than one workbook open, so you might want to use variables to make this cleaner like this:

```
Sub UpdateFileInfo()

    Dim LocalWorkbook As Workbook
    Dim RemoteWorkbook As Workbook

    Set LocalWorkbook = ActiveWorkbook

    If (Range("B1") = "") Then
        Range("A2:R200").Value = ""
    Else
        FullFilename = Range("B1").Value
        Set RemoteWorkbook = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=FullFilename, ReadOnly:=True)

        LocalWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("A2:R200") = RemoteWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("A2:R200").Value

        RemoteWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=False
    End If
End Sub
```

In general, when you get a subscription-out-of-range error, it's because you are referring to an element of a collection (in this case the workbooks collection) or an element of an array using a key or an index that does not exist.

Comment: Why do I have to have the workbook open to copy data from it? Is there any way to copy it without opening another workbook? Also, by adding the line you mentioned I'm getting another error 1004

Comment: As far as I know, you either have to open the workbook or refresh formulas referring to it to get data from a workbook.

Comment: Opening file in read-only makes it pretty fast and you can close the workbook at the end. But if you really don't want to open the workbook, you could put formulas in the local workbook that refer to the remote workbook and then replace them by their values right after refreshing.